# How can I count and display the amount of times my program has been run?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a text based game that once finished should write certain variables to a text file:

```
==============
Story0: 
-----------
Players name: name
Players characteristic: characteristic
```

This works fine, however what I wish to implement is a way for the function this
text comes from to also display *which* story it is generating meaning that it would write: `StoryX` on the `X`'th time that the program has been run.

I am unfamiliar with writing to and reading from python files and I'm afraid I am very far off what would be the best solution. The following code represents what I have so far (providing an error):

```
def Endscript(numberofcycles):
    with open("playerstories.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write("================\n")
        f.write("Story" + str(numberofcycles) + ": \n")
        f.write("-----------\n")
        f.write("Players name: " + Player.name)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("Players characteristic: " + Player.char)
        f.write("\n")
    with open("number.txt", "r") as f:
        numberofcycles = f.readline()
        numberofcycles = int(numberofcycles)
        numberofcycles += 1
    with open("number.txt", "w") as f:
        numberofcycles = str(numberofcycles)
        f.write(numberofcycles)
```

What I have attempted to do here is to change the value of a number, (yes just one number) from within the `number.txt` file in accordance with the changing `X` value.

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: You need to write `playerstories.txt` AFTER getting  `numberofcycles` from your file, and remove `numberofcycles` from the argument list of your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
def Endscript():
    with open("playerstories.txt", 'a') as f:
        with open("number.txt", "r") as file:
            numberofcycles = file.readline()
            numberofcycles = int(numberofcycles)
        f.write("================\n")
        f.write("Story" + str(numberofcycles) + ": \n")
        f.write("-----------\n")
        f.write("Players name: " + Player.name)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("Players characteristic: " + Player.char)
        f.write("\n")
        with open("number.txt", "w") as f:
            numberofcycles += 1
            numberofcycles = str(numberofcycles)
            f.write(numberofcycles)
```

The error is caused by the undefined numberofcycles, if so it is because you haven't read into the txt file to retrieve the numberofcycles.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, just remember that each run your game will be a completely independent process so your `Endscript()` function really does not know the `numberofcycles` unless you have already read that from disk. Here is quick function to access a single file and increment the value each time, returning that value for your use.

```py
import os

def increment_counter(file_name):
    if not os.path.exists(file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
            fp.write("1")
        return 1
    else:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as fp:
            current_count = int(fp.read().strip())
        with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
            fp.write(str(current_count + 1))
        return current_count + 1
    
fname = 'test_counter.txt'
print(increment_counter(fname))
print(increment_counter(fname))
print(increment_counter(fname))
print(increment_counter(fname))
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

You can couple this with a `reset_counter()` which just deletes the file to reset it